# Multiple Controllers inside MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to get more of a grasp of the MVC pattern, and have a theoretical application:

A Client application that has it's own view that is requesting data from a Server application that connects to a database and returns the requested data back to the Client view. The client has its own small database that performs small queries that are displayed in client views.

The question is: Are there multiple controllers here? One on each the client and another on the Server, or am I trying to apply the wrong pattern to this problem?

If this is posted on the wrong site, feel free to migrate it, and if you need more explanation I'll try to explain it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC pattern applies to a user interface. It also applies to the whole system, which in your case, is the client AND the server too. From what you said, your client can have an MVC inside it because it does the display. The server may interact with the M part of of the MVC pattern implementation. But I don't think the server part of your system has much of the MVC pattern implemented inside it.

Sometimes it is useful to think of the client as a user for the server, the server as a self-contained system-in-a-system and the server's client interface as having a sort of MVC with a very limited set of control actions and very rigid view. I don't think that would be useful here.